# Wix Toolset tried to load setup files from ISO drive that is no longer mapped

Tags: wix

I have an installer that uses .NET Framework 4.8.  We distribute the product electronically in an ISO.  In most modern OS'es you double click on the ISO, it maps it to a drive and you install from there.

The problem comes in when it needs to reboot after the .NET install and the ISO is no longer mapped after the reboot.  So the folder where the install was prior to the reboot non longer exists.

Does the bootstrapper copy all the setup files to a temp directory on the machine or is the only answer to this to require that the ISO get mapped through the reboot?

Comment: Not sure why you chose the ISO format for distribution. Can you quickly describe the reasons why this is preferable? Use with virtuals maybe? Could you deliver in both formats?

Comment: The ISO part is out of my hands.  They do CRC's on the ISO image etc., probably something to do with regulatory stuff, that I don't know.  If it were files on a USB drive or on a CD or in a folder this would work fine.